# Scikit-learn StackingClassifier with missing values

Tags: scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

When I call `model.predict_proba(X)` on my `StackingClassifier` model the run execution crashes because the library is calling a method `assert_all_finite()` to check whether my dataframe contains missing values.
Since the estimators I stacked are able to handle missing values, I don't see the reason why this should happen and I didn't find anything in the documentation that says that the `StackingClassifier` requires data without missing values.

It's a bit hard for me to come up with a short reproducibile snippet of code given that it comes from several layers of model abstraction, but I can print out the model effectively raising the error call.

```
p = model.predict_proba(X_loyal)
```

where `model` is:

```
StackingClassifier(estimators=[('ExtraTreesClassifier_117',
                                ExtraTreesClassifier(bootstrap=True,
                                                     class_weight={0: 1, 1: 5},
                                                     criterion='entropy',
                                                     max_depth=11,
                                                     max_features='log2',
                                                     max_samples=0.5946040593595099,
                                                     min_samples_leaf=2,
                                                     n_estimators=163,
                                                     random_state=117)),
                               ('RandomForestClassifier_117',
                                RandomForestClassifier(class_weight={0: 1,
                                                                     1: 5},
                                                       criterion='entropy',
                                                       max_depth=11,
                                                       max_features='log2',
                                                       max_samples=0.5946040593595099,
                                                       min_samples_leaf=2,
                                                       n_estimators=163,
                                                       random_state=117)),
                               ('LGBMClassifier_117',
                                LGBMClassifier(class_weight={0: 1, 1: 1},
                                               deterministic=True, max_depth=9,
                                               n_estimators=183, num_leaves=3,
                                               subsample=0.2986274713775564,
                                               verbose=-1))])
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mlpoc/miniconda3/envs/churn/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3417, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-12-eafa75c49322>", line 1, in <module>
    model.predict_proba(X_loyal)
  File "/home/mlpoc/miniconda3/envs/churn/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/metaestimators.py", line 120, in <lambda>
    out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mlpoc/miniconda3/envs/churn/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_stacking.py", line 485, in predict_proba
    return self.final_estimator_.predict_proba(self.transform(X))
  File "/home/mlpoc/miniconda3/envs/churn/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_stacking.py", line 522, in transform
    return self._transform(X)
  File "/home/mlpoc/miniconda3/envs/churn/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_stacking.py", line 215, in _transform
    predictions = [
  File "/home/mlpoc/miniconda3/envs/churn/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_stacking.py", line 216, in <listcomp>
    getattr(est, meth)(X)
  File "/home/mlpoc/miniconda3/envs/churn/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py", line 674, in predict_proba
    X = self._validate_X_predict(X)
  File "/home/mlpoc/miniconda3/envs/churn/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py", line 422, in _validate_X_predict
    return self.estimators_[0]._validate_X_predict(X, check_input=True)
  File "/home/mlpoc/miniconda3/envs/churn/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/tree/_classes.py", line 407, in _validate_X_predict
    X = self._validate_data(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csr",
  File "/home/mlpoc/miniconda3/envs/churn/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 421, in _validate_data
    X = check_array(X, **check_params)
  File "/home/mlpoc/miniconda3/envs/churn/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 63, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mlpoc/miniconda3/envs/churn/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 720, in check_array
    _assert_all_finite(array,
  File "/home/mlpoc/miniconda3/envs/churn/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 103, in _assert_all_finite
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').
```

Versions

```
sklearn.__version__
Out[6]: '0.24.2'
lightgbm.__version__
Out[8]: '3.2.1'
```

Comment: Please provide a full error traceback, and preferably a minimal reproducible example (including dataset).  It may be the same issue as https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/21743, in which case a fix should be included in the upcoming PR.  (That Issue also gives a minimal example which you could probably adapt.)

Comment: Thanks @BenReiniger - I added what I could and thanks for link reference. It is indeed the same type of error, it's very likely connected to that even though I don't have pipelines. It could be due to the Random Forest estimator like there and some wrong default tag settings.

Comment: It looks like you've cut off the error message.  And I thought (sklearn's) Extra-trees and Random Forest didn't handle missing values?

Comment: Sorry @BenReiniger, just fixed that. Shouldn't I get an error from the individual estimator? So that I can potentially make a try catch statement?

Comment: the error _is_ being raised by one of the two forest models, it seems; about halfway through the traceback.  (Did the training data not have any missings?)

Comment: Hi @BenReiniger - yes, the data does have it. You understood that it's one of the two forest models because one path that rose the error links to a `_forest.py` file, correct?
Now I see it's not feasible what I meant to do. When I call `_predict_proba` only one error is rose and thus it is not possible to `try catch` the ValueError in order to let the module that can handle missing values get the original dataframe and for the other models pass by an imputed versione of the dataframe.
I guess I should close the question, as I don't see a follow up, am I right?